# Create custom View group(Diagonal Layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a custom diagonal layout like androids predefined linear layout..so i started with a class extending ViewGroup and overrided OnLayout and OnMeasure methods..However I am finding it difficult to understand  where to write the logic for alligning all the Views such that they will be placed diagonally

I read few blogs on it [How to Create Custom Layout in Android by Extending ViewGroup Class](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class)

Also followed the google I/O video
But still not clear about how to get started with creating a diagonal layout..can someone suggest any additional resources in this regard..???

Answer (score 1):

The logic to measure children should be in `onMeasure`. In here, you want the sum of all children height to be as big as the height given in the `heightMeasureSpec`. Same goes for the width.
To do so, you can divide the width and height from measureSpec by the number of children, and call the child views `measure` method with those computed values.

The logic to position the children is in `onLayout`. In here, you call the child views `layout` method one after another, passing it positions (left, top, ...) incremented after layouting each child.

You must take care of child views margins in both methods, as well as your container padding.

Lucas Rocha has a very good [article](http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/) (with lot of reverse engineering) for custom views.